# Can two Magento Installations on different server share the same users table?

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I have 2 running Magento installations on different servers. Both use their own database in their environment. Now I need to share the users accounts between those 2 websites, so if the user is logged in website A and then navigate to website B he/she will be logged in also How can I achieve this?

I have unrestricted access to my both servers including the databases. Is it possible to manage the systems in a way, that a Magento user account loggedin into server A can access his Magento account on server B without a new login as well?

Comment: Please provide a little more information about your setup, e.g. what are the databases for now? How are the two sites isolated?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone let say I have abc.com which is a standalone magento application, and xyz.com also magento application on different server.

Comment: Do you have root permissions? Is the database accessible from remote, i.e. listening on remote address?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I have a full access for both.

Comment: I've improved your question providing a little more information. If your can add further information, click the link "edit" below your question.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone thank you

Comment: You also should clarify if you only want the logins to be the same or if a user actively logged in into server A should have access into server B without logging in again. Latter one will be more complicated due to same origin policies of browsers when sharing session ids.